# Attribute routing in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass an extra parameter to an ActionResult() function. I have a JavaScript file that contains a function called AddCustomCourse().

```
function AddCustomCourse() {
    var formModal = new QCI.BootstrapFormModal.BootstrapFormModal(window.pageVars.AddCustomCourseUrl, {
        title: "Add Custom Course",
        actionButtonText: "Add Course",
        beforeSubmitAction: UpdateCKEditors,
        successCallback: UpdateDataTables,
    });

    formModal.OpenModal();
}
```

I have defined a pageVar variable in the index.cshtml page called AddCutomCourseUrl that calls a helper URL method:

```
<script>
    var pageVars = {
        AddCustomCourseUrl: '@Url.Admin_CurriculumCourses_AddCustomCourse(Model.curriculumID)',
    }
</script>
```

Here is the definition of the helper function:

```
 public static string Admin_CurriculumCourses_AddCustomCourse(this UrlHelper helper, int curriculumID)
    {
      return helper.RouteUrl(new { area = "Admin", controller = "CurriculumCourses", action = "AddCustomCourse", curriculumID });
    }
```

and here is the ActionResult method:

```
  [HttpGet, Route("AddCustomCourse")]
    public ActionResult AddCustomCourse(int curriculumID)
    {
      var viewModel = _curriculumService.GetAddDetailsForCustomCourse(curriculumID, CurrentUser.UserID);
      return this.Json(new JsonResultVM(true, this.RenderPartialViewToString("_AddCustomCourse", viewModel)), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The model I am passing contains two variables, curriculumID & userID. I am trying to pass the userID along with the curriculumID. I have already made sure that both variables are getting set; however when I change the previous functions to add the extra parameter, userID is always null and currivulumID is passed fine. Here is what I did:

```
<script>
    var pageVars = {
        AddCustomCourseUrl: '@Url.Admin_CurriculumCourses_AddCustomCourse(Model.curriculumID, Model.userID)',
    }
</script>
```

```
 public static string Admin_CurriculumCourses_AddCustomCourse(this UrlHelper helper, int curriculumID, int? selectedUserID)
    {
      return helper.RouteUrl(new { area = "Admin", controller = "CurriculumCourses", action = "AddCustomCourse", curriculumID, selectedUserID });
    }
```

```
[HttpGet, Route("AddCustomCourse")]
    public ActionResult AddCustomCourse(int curriculumID, int? selectedUserID)
    {
      var viewModel = _curriculumService.GetAddDetailsForCustomCourse(curriculumID, selectedUserID, CurrentUser.UserID);
      return this.Json(new JsonResultVM(true, this.RenderPartialViewToString("_AddCustomCourse", viewModel)), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: did you try changing your route to `[HttpGet("AddCustomCourse/{curriculumID}/{selectedUserID}")]`

Comment: Yes, that still got the curriculumID, but not the SelectedUserID

Answer (score 0):

You are not putting optional in your last parameter.

```
[HttpGet("AddCustomCourse/{curriculumID}/{selectedUserID?}")] // <= Your Last Parameter is optional,sometimes may be null so add ? behind the parameter name.
public ActionResult AddCustomCourse(int curriculumID,int? selectedUserID) // Then it accept parameter. 
{
      // You should validate the model. 
      if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);
      var viewModel = _curriculumService.GetAddDetailsForCustomCourse(curriculumID, selectedUserID, CurrentUser.UserID);
      return this.Json(new JsonResultVM(true, this.RenderPartialViewToString("_AddCustomCourse", viewModel)), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: what version of dotnet core are u using? this code working fine in my project. tested with .net core 2.1